# PyPDF2: Error -5 while decompressing data: incomplete or truncated stream

Tags: pdf, zlib, pypdf

I'm having problem with Incomplete or truncated stream while trying to pull data out of PDF interactive form. Could anyone help me with this please

```
PDFfile = open(fname, "rb")
pdfread = p2.PdfFileReader(PDFfile)
```

I'm having below error when i execute pdfread

```
Error -5 while decompressing data: incomplete or truncated stream
```

Comment: You appear to work with a defect pdf.

Comment: I have the same issue with PDF files that can be opened with Acrobat properly.

Answer (score 0):

It mostly happens when you already opened pdf in different program or pdf is is corrupted. Try opening pdf with open()